# How to disable right click in jxbrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

I am loading a webpage in jxbrowser in java swing, I want to block or disable right click on that page, I searched but not got the answer, please let me know if any one has any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, finally I have a working solution for disabling right click

```
final Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);


view.setMouseEventsHandler(new InputEventsHandler<MouseEvent>() {           
        @Override
        public boolean handle(MouseEvent arg0) {                
            if(arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest JxBrowser has major API changes. If you are using 7.* or above the approach is as follows.

```
browser.set(MoveMouseWheelCallback.class, params -> Response.suppress());
```

**Available Callbacks**

- EnterMouseCallback
- ExitMouseCallback
- MoveMouseCallback
- MoveMouseWheelCallback
- PressKeyCallback
- PressMouseCallback
- ReleaseKeyCallback
- ReleaseMouseCallback
- TypeKeyCallback

**Links**

[What's New](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/release-notes/2019/v7-1.html#whats-new)

[API Documentation](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/javadoc/7.12.2/index.html)